# Wordpress passing ajax value to a specific page using Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like to pass a variable to a specific page. I found a simple example explaining how to use ajax with wordpress.

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
var fruit = 'Banana';

// This does the ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action':'example_ajax_request',
        'fruit' : fruit
    },
    success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});  

});
```

**Piece of PHP to insert in `functions.php`**

```
function example_ajax_request() {

// The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

    $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];

    // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
    if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
        $fruit = 'Apple';
    }

    // Now we'll return it to the javascript function
    // Anything outputted will be returned in the response
    echo $fruit;

    // If you're debugging, it might be useful to see what was sent in the $_REQUEST
    // print_r($_REQUEST);

}

// Always die in functions echoing ajax content
  die();
 }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );


   wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' =>   admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Unfortunately I cannot pass the variable. I inspected the code and I get this error:

```html
Error: ajax_object is not defined
```

Do you maybe know another way to obtain the same result?

Comment: **wp_localize_script** would expect to have a variable with the name **ajax_object**, so can you try to comment this and see if it works so you'll know that the error is coming form there?

Comment: Hi, LoicTheAtzec
I did not quite understand your example.
May I ask you to write your suggestion using blockquote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are very near, but there is some little things missing…

What I mean in my comment, is that you need to use it this way using `'ajax-script'` in both:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts'); 
add_js_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

Changed **`$_REQUEST`** to **`$_POST`:**

```
function example_ajax_request() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_POST) ) {

        $fruit = $_POST['fruit'];

        // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }

        // Now we'll return it to the javascript function
        // Anything outputted will be returned in the response
        echo $fruit;

        // If you're debugging, it might be useful to see what was sent in the $_POST
        // print_r($_POST);

    }

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
      die();

 }
```

Added `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ … )`**:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' ); // <= this one
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

For your jQuery script `script.js` file, there is 2 important missing little things:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /* We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request */
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    /* This does the ajax request */
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, /* <====== missing here */
        type : 'post', /*    <========== and missing here */
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            /* This outputs the result of the ajax request */
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  

});
```

This should work now…

References:

- [Using AJAX With PHP on Your WordPress Site Without a Plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/?trm=b&utm_expid=3606929-67.9mTA3ZaTSnSYStWsvDePTw.1)
- [How to use Ajax with your WordPress Plugin or Theme?](https://statenweb.com/uncategorized/how-to-use-ajax-with-your-wordpress-plugin-or-theme/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **wp_localize_script** wrong. In the PHP code, remove the `wp_localize_script` line.

Optionally you can (and should) add the following

```
// this line is for users who are not logged in
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except you have to add
ajax_object.ajax_url rather than ajaxurl in url: parameter of $.ajax function as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
var fruit = 'Banana';

// This does the ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: **ajax_object.ajax_url**,
    data: {
        'action':'example_ajax_request',
        'fruit' : fruit
    },
    success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});  

});
```

copy and paste above script in place of your $.ajax function
If you want to see what is ajax_object.ajax_url then
alert it inisde your code and it will alert path to your admin ajax file
which is required for using ajax in wordpress