# Wordpress: Ajax not working to insert, query and result data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

On my site, through a `form` I send/register same information in database, do a `SELECT`/query and return it! Return the last table saved in database, just that user just entered on the form (along with some more information coming from the database).

How I want to display these values coming from databse in a `modal bootstrap` it's necessary that the page doesn't give the refresh. For this, I inserted the `AJAX` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#enviar').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            //CALL AJAX IN WORDPRESS 
            url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',              
            //INSERT, QUERY AND DISPLAYS TO USER      
            data: 'action=prancha',                  
            error: function(){
                alert('ERRO!!!');
            },
            //IF OK, DISPLAYS TO USER IN DIV "RESULT"
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

In my functions.php file:

```
function prancha(){
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  include "../../../wp-config.php";


      /* DECLARING THE VARIABLES  */
  $nome = "";
  $email = "";
  $estilo = "";
  $experiencia = "";
  $altura = "";
  $peso = "";

  // VALIDATION
  if(!empty($_POST)){     
     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $estilo = $_POST['estilo'];
     $experiencia = $_POST['experiencia'];
     $altura = $_POST['altura'];
     $peso = $_POST['peso'];

     cadastra_user($nome, $email, $estilo, $experiencia, $altura, $peso);
 }


  //INSERT IN DATABASE NAME, EMAIL, ESTILE, EXPERIENCE, HEIGHT AND WEIGHT
function cadastra_user($nome, $email, $estilo, $experiencia, $altura, $peso){          
    global $wpdb;

    $table = 'user';

    $data = array(      
      'nome' => $nome,
      'email' => $email,
      'estilo' => $estilo,
      'exp' => $experiencia,
      'altura' => $altura,
      'peso' => $peso,
    );

    $updated = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    if ( ! $updated ) {
      $wpdb->print_error();
    }    
}   

//CONECT WITH DATABASE TO DO THE SELECT
include "db.php";

  function BuscaAlgo($conexao){

  // QUERY + INNER JOIN IN DATABASE
 $query = "SELECT  USU.usuario,
                   USU.nome,
                   USU.exp,
                   USU.altura,
                   USU.peso,
                   PRAN.exp_ref,
                   PRAN.altura_ref,
                   PRAN.peso_ref,
                   PRAN.tipo_prancha,
                   PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
                   PRAN.meio_prancha, 
                   PRAN.litragem_prancha       
                    FROM DADOS_USUARIO AS USU 
                         INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN
                             on USU.exp = PRAN.exp_ref
                              WHERE USU.altura = PRAN.altura_ref
                                AND USU.peso = PRAN.peso_ref
                                  ORDER BY USU.usuario DESC LIMIT 1";



  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

  $retorno = array();

  while($experiencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $retorno[] = $experiencia;
  }

 return $resultado;
}


//DISPLAYS THE QUERY TO USER      
$resultado = array();
$resultado = BuscaAlgo($conexao);

foreach($resultado as $valor){
    echo $valor["usuario"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["nome"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["exp"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["altura"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["peso"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    print("///////");
    echo $valor["tipo_prancha"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["tamanho_prancha"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["meio_prancha"]; print(".  .  .  ."); 
    echo $valor["litragem_prancha"];  
}  


    die(); //END THE EXECUTION
}
//ADD THE AJAX HOOKS IN WORDPRESS
add_action('wp_ajax_prancha', 'prancha');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_prancha', 'prancha');
```

The code is commenting, basically I did:

AJAX:

- In the field `URL` call the native Wordpress `admin-ajax.php`.
- In the field `DATA` call the function that makes the registration, query and displays to the user.
- In the `SUCCESS` field, prints the value of `data`.

FUNCTIONS: I make the registration code in database, do the query and print with the `echo`.

The `AJAX` is returning me the error message.

How can I solve this?

What am I doing wrong?

*Note1: When I insert the code that is in my 'functions`, the registration code, the query and the`echo' to displays in a direct way, in my `footer.php`, it works. Therefore, we can understand that the error is not even in the code of insert,query or displays. 


NOTE 2: I want to display the return of database within a `modal boostrap`. At first I'm just displaying on the screen, to check that everything is OK. After that I will research on how to put these data into the `modal`, although not the main subject of the post, suggestions for how to do this are also welcome.*

Comment: If you are using WordPress jQuery calls should be made using 'jQuery' rather than '$' so as to avoid conflicts and to keep within the expect best practise.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you  should use $wpdb object to access the database in Wordpress, including the select. Check the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

You didn't specify what kind of error you get, but I think your ajax call definition is wrong, it should be:

```
data: {
  action : 'prancha' 
}
```

Comment: It's the error of `AJAX` itself. The field `error: function(){ alert('ERRO!!!');},`

Comment: made the modifications you suggested, still having the same error.

Comment: Check the Network tab in Google Chrome developer console to see exactly what's going on in the request.

Answer (score 1):

There is some mistakes in your code, but you have just missed a very important part of code, 
to make it work, the `wp_localize_script()` function:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'meu_ajax_scripts'); 
meu_ajax_scripts(){
    // Register your script (located in a subfolder `js` of your active theme, for example here)
    wp_enqueue_script( 'meuscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ajax_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    // Making the bridge between php and javascript:
    wp_localize_script( 'meuscript', 'meuajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

*This code goes in the function.php file of your active theme  (or child theme) folder… If it is a child theme you have to replace `get_template_directory_uri()` by `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.*

As you can see `'meuscript'` is in both functions  `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_localize_script()`.

Then you will retrieve `'meuajax'` and `'ajaxurl'` in your `jQuery` script.

They are combined this way: 
`url: meuajax.ajaxurl,` instead of `url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',`. 
The **`wp_localize_script()`** function will make the bridge through `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` function from your `jQuery script` to your `php` function…

---

***(NEW UPDATE - NOVA ATUALIZAÇÃO)*** 
regarding your comments, your answer/question update, and this [**thread**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185164/79855) too…

---

So here is your **newly** updated jQuery code *(with a different approach related to form data)*. All the form data is serialized before being sent to your `prancha()` php function through ajax:

```js
// We use jQuery instead of $. Thanks to Phill Healey (see comments).
// Then we put back the $ shorthand in the function… 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    // Now we can use $ shorthand, avoiding javascript errors (with wordpress). 
    $('#enviar').submit(function(e){ // Updated            

        var minhaprancha = $(this).serialize(); // serializing the form data

        e.preventDefault(); // preventing form submit normal behavior

        //ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST', 
            action: 'prancha', 
            url:    meuscript.ajaxurl, // the functional url     
            data:   meuscript.minhaprancha, // all the data of the form (serialized)

            // Displaying succes message
            success: function( data ){
                $('#result').html( 'Sucesso : '.data );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(data);
            },

            // Displaying error message     
            error: function( error ){
                $('#result').html( 'Erro! : '. error );
                // for debugging purpose in browser js console
                console.log(error);
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

*Put this code in a js file ajax_script.js inside a js subfolder of your active theme (or child theme).*

---

Your html form *(an example like)*, has to be some kind of similar as this one:

```
<form method="post" id="minhaprancha"> // this id is important too (no "action" needed)

    <label for="Seu nome">From *</label>
    <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu nome" required>
    <br />

    <label for="Seu email">From *</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu email" required>
    <br />

    <label for="Seu estilo">From *</label>
    <input name="estilo" id="estilo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu estilo" required>
    <br />

    <label for="Seu experiencia">From *</label>
    <input name="experiencia" id="experiencia" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu experiencia" required>
    <br />

    <label for="Seu altura">From *</label>
    <input name="altura" id="altura" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu altura" required>
    <br />

    <label for="Seu peso">From *</label>
    <input name="peso" id="peso" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu peso" required>
    <br />

    <?php 
    // This imput hidden element has the name value of the php function ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="prancha"/>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
<div id="result" class="result"></div>
```

---

Then you will retrieve (as you already know) the data values in your php with:

```
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $estilo = $_POST['estilo'];
 $experiencia = $_POST['experiencia'];
 $altura = $_POST['altura'];
 $peso = $_POST['peso'];
```

This time this is a turnkey solution, and **it will work**, once you have adapted your form to it.

References:

- [Wordpress passing ajax value to a specific page using Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678914/wordpress-passing-ajax-value-to-a-specific-page-using-wordpress/37685212#37685212)
- [Using AJAX With PHP on Your WordPress Site Without a Plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/?trm=b&utm_expid=3606929-67.9mTA3ZaTSnSYStWsvDePTw.1)
- [How to use Ajax with your WordPress Plugin or Theme?](https://statenweb.com/uncategorized/how-to-use-ajax-with-your-wordpress-plugin-or-theme/)
- [How can I get form data with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276463/how-can-i-get-form-data-with-javascript-jquery)
- [WPSE - Custom Form with Ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185164/79855)

Answer (score 0):

First, I am grateful for their willingness to help.
Second, I prefer search more about how to solve my issue before coming here with feedback.

The code you sent me, still not working. I made some changes and it worked in parts.

- I replaced the `submit` for `click` in my jQuery and I also replaced the type of my button for `text`.
- I replaced the `this` of `serialize()` for id of my form.

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
          $('#enviar').click(function(e){   //I replaced the `SUBMIT` for `CLICK`
              var minhaprancha = $('#minhaprancha').serialize(); // I replaced the `THIS` for id of my form

  ```
          e.preventDefault(); // preventing form submit normal behavior

          $.ajax({
              type:   'POST',              
              url:   meuajax.ajaxurl,
              data:  meuajax.minhaprancha,
              success: function( data ){
                  $('#resultado').html( 'Sucesso : ' + data );
                  console.log(data);
              },  
              error: function( error ){
                  $('#resultado').html( 'Erro! : ' + error );
                  console.log(error);
              }               
      });
  });
  ```

  });

With these modifications, the code worked, but not perfectly. I put a `alert`to check if the `serialize()` was working and it is!. But, in the end of script, the browser console returns me status success, value zero and isn't being made the operation of the function `prancha()`. The data is not registered in the database.

[image: SUCCESS]

> I looked for other ways to try to make the work code:

Getting the values of the fields, keeping a variable and calling it in ajax. Both saving the fields of the form as a variable declared in direct `data` field and is displayed the Internal Error 500

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $('#enviar').click(function(e){ 
        var minhaprancha = '$nome='+$("#nome").val()+
                           '&email='+$("#email").val()+
                           '&estilo='+$("#estilo").val()+
                           '&experiencia='+$("#experiencia").val()+
                           '&altura='+$("#altura").val()+
                           '&peso='+$("#peso").val();  //GETTING THE VALUES OF FIELDS

        e.preventDefault(); // preventing form submit normal behavior

        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST',              
            url:   meuajax.ajaxurl,              
            data: { action: 'prancha', minhaprancha },
            success: function( data ){
                $('#resultado').html( 'Sucesso : ' + data );
                console.log(data);
            },

            error: function( error ){
                $('#resultado').html( 'Erro! : ' + error );
                console.log(error);
            }               
        });
    });
  });
```

[image: INTERNAL ERROR 500]

> I also tried to call the values of the form fields in `data : {}` matrix and is displayed the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        $('#enviar').click(function(e){         
        e.preventDefault(); // preventing form submit normal behavior

            $.ajax({
                type:   'POST',              
                url:   meuajax.ajaxurl,  
                action: 'prancha',
                data: {  'nome':nome, 'email':email, 'estilo':estilo, 'experiencia':experiencia, 'altura':altura, 'peso':peso },
                success: function( data ){
                    $('#resultado').html( 'Sucesso : ' + data );
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function( error ){
                    $('#resultado').html( 'Erro! : ' + error );
                    console.log(error);
                }               
        });
    });
});
```

[image: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

> In my `functions.php`, I left only the part that insert the data in the database. To see the operation in parts. And remember that, when I put this code directly into my `footer.php` it works perfectly:

```
function meu_ajax_scripts(){    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'meuajax', get_template_directory_uri().'/consulta.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'meuajax', 'meuajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'meu_ajax_scripts');

function prancha(){ 

    if(!empty($_POST)){
     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $estilo = $_POST['estilo'];
     $experiencia = $_POST['experiencia'];
     $altura = $_POST['altura'];
     $peso = $_POST['peso'];

     cadastra_usuario($nome, $email, $estilo, $experiencia, $altura, $peso);
    }

    function cadastra_usuario($nome, $email, $estilo, $experiencia, $altura, $peso){          

         global $wpdb;

        $table = 'dados_usuario';

        $data = array(      
          'nome' => $nome,
          'email' => $email,
          'estilo' => $estilo,
          'experiencia' => $experiencia,
          'altura' => $altura,
          'peso' => $peso,
        );

        $updated = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

        if ( ! $updated ) {
          $wpdb->print_error();
        }

    }
    die(); 
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_prancha', 'prancha');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_prancha', 'prancha');
```

I'm still researching on various blogs, websites and forums trying to work it.