# Why wp-ajax in front end it return 0 but in the admin it works correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

These are the functions I used them in plugin. It works in backend but in frontend it respons `0`. I copy past the same code and also prefer `admin_enqueue_scripts` with `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
global $wpdb;
$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
$whatever += 10;
    echo $whatever;
wp_die();
}

function testajax(){
var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'whatever': ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
};

jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
};
```

I used it by `onClick` event.

I used also

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

for admin and

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

for frontend

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {

wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script',    get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_query.js', array('jquery') );


  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );   
}
```

This is the script I want to be loaded in my custom page just in custom page but it doesn't load in custom page. For loading I must use it in functions.php, then when I use it in functions.php, it will be loaded in all pages as it says in comments. There is the problem.

Comment: There are some missing little things in your code. Please Have a look to [**this related thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37685212/3730754) or [**This one too**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37919380/3730754)

Comment: i used the same thing happened with your examples

Comment: It could be easier to see what is wrong, if you update your question with all your code… thanks

Comment: i update it can you check it now please

Comment: All this is not correct. What do you want to do exactly… is very unclear. Clarify your question. Giving details about what, how and where you want to do? Explain the purpose. What event is going to trigger ajax? … You are melting everything… sorry, until you clarify things, I can't help

Answer (score 0):

Ajax URL isn't available on front-end by default. You must localize it before using:

```
wp_localize_script('my_enqueue', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('wp-ajax.php')));
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that the URL you're trying to call doesn't exist in the Admin? Try using `ajaxurl` instead of `ajax_object.ajax_url`