# Using ajax to create a filter selector for WooCommerce products

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create an ajax filter selector for WooCommerce products, without any plugins.

But I don't know how to approach this problem.

I have this list of product with the dropdown to select the kind of filter:

[image: screenshot of shop page]

I use this code to show the list:

```
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'list', 'product' ); ?>
```

I know that the **`<div>`** class that I have to replace is **`'.products'`**, but I have  to change the **`$post`** to change the attribute by low price , hight price or alphabetical orden, and I don't find any solution.

This is my function to change the div when I select a element when I change the dropdown

```
$('#filter_paradise').change ->
  valor = $('#filter_paradise option:selected').val()
  changepost(valor)
  return
```

when I change the dropdown I call changepost function with the select value, this function replace the div with the new value, but before that, call to filter_product function

```
changepost = (valor) ->
  value = valor
  request = $.ajax(
    url: ajax_object.ajax_url
    method: 'POST'
    data:
      opc: value
      action: 'filter_product'
      dataType: "json"
    success: (html, data) ->
      #$('.products').replaceWith(html); 
      console.log 'change'
      return
    error: (errorThrown) ->
      console.log errorThrown
      return
  )
  return
```

This function is in function.php, in this function I have there values, the country, the category and the value select by the filter I need this values to create the query and order by low price, hight price or alphabetical

```
function filter_product(){
  $last_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  $country = $last_uri[6];
  $getcategoria = explode('=',$last_uri[7]);
  $categoria = $getcategoria[1];
    $args = null;
  echo json_encode($categoria);
  exit();

}
```

Before to `$('.products').replaceWith(html);` in changepost function

I have to change the $args in:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The div that I have to replace is in `<?php wc_get_template_part( 'list', 'product' ); ?>` this partial is in `archive-product.php` this view is like this.

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
<?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="elementos_lista">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <?php wc_get_template_part( 'list', 'product' ); ?>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php //wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<div class="map_paradise"></div>
```

and before to execute the loop I have to get a new $args to the query with the new parameters, order by price or alphabetical.

What I am doing wrong?
Is there an other way to do that?

Any idea to point me on the right direction is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Using WordPress Ajax involve different/separated things: 1) The jQuery script. 2) the function that contains wp_enqueue_script() and wp_localize_script(). 3) The php ajax function related to add_action('wp_ajax_ …) &  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ …) that receive the data and filter products in the loop. 4) The selector html/php code (related to jQuery)... After that in your code I notice that you are also passing "categories" data through ajax, and that is not clear, because you don't mention that in your question. Also where is the code of your loop? …

Comment: Kindly, you need **to edit your question**, and **separate code in 4 sections with explanations**, mentioning too **the categories data you are trying to pass through ajax**. What are that categories for? what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec I edit my question.

Comment: Ok try to take example on [**this thread (answer)**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37685212/3730754). This is the correct process for Ajax… so where is your php hooked function with `add_action('wp_ajax_ …)` & `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ …)`?  Could you add also your selector html code? … After that I should be able to help you…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I create a Filter, this is my solution

I create my dropdown

```
<div class="filter_paradise">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <select id="filter_paradise" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="1">High Price</option>
        <option value="2">Low Price</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When my dropdown change I call this function

```
$('#filter_paradise').change ->
  valor = $('#filter_paradise option:selected').val()
  changepost(valor)
  return

changepost = (valor) ->
  value = valor
  request = $.ajax(
    url: ajax_object.ajax_url
    method: 'POST'
    data:
      opc: value
      action: 'filter_product'
      dataType: "json"
    success: (html, data) ->
      $('.products').replaceWith(html); 
      console.log 'change'
      return
    error: (errorThrown) ->
      console.log errorThrown
      return
  )
  return
```

and finally I call a function `filter_product` in function.php to change my div

```
function filter_product(){
  $select_opc = $_POST['opc'];
  $last_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  $country = $last_uri[4];
  $getcategoria = explode('=',$last_uri[5]);
  $categoria = $getcategoria[1];
  // var_dump($last_uri);
  // var_dump($categoria);
  // var_dump($country);
  wp_reset_query();

  if (!empty($categoria)):
    switch ($select_opc) {
      case 0:
        $args = array( 
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'      =>  -1,
        'orderby'             => 'title',
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'product_cat'         => $categoria,
        'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_country',
            'terms'           => $country,
            'field'           => 'name',
            //'operator'        => 'IN'
            )
          )
        );
        break;
      case 1:
        $args = array( 
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'      =>  -1,
        'meta_key'            => '_price',
        'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'product_cat'         => $categoria,
        'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_country',
            'terms'           => $country,
            'field'           => 'name',
            //'operator'        => 'IN'
            )
          )
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        $args = array( 
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'      =>  -1,
        'meta_key'            => '_price',
        'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'product_cat'         => $categoria,
        'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_country',
            'terms'           => $country,
            'field'           => 'name',
            //'operator'        => 'IN'
            )
          )
        );
        break;
      default:
        # code...
        break;
    }
    else:
      switch ($select_opc) {
        case 0:
          $args = array( 
          'post_type'           => 'product',
          'post_status'         => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'      =>  -1,
          'orderby'             => 'title',
          'order'               => 'ASC',
          'product_cat'         => $country
          );
          break;
        case 1:
          $args = array( 
          'post_type'           => 'product',
          'post_status'         => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'      =>  -1,
          'meta_key'            => '_price',
          'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
          'order'               => 'DESC',
          'product_cat'         => $country
          );
          break;
        case 2:
          $args = array( 
          'post_type'           => 'product',
          'post_status'         => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'      =>  -1,
          'meta_key'            => '_price',
          'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
          'order'               => 'ASC',
          'product_cat'         => $country
          );
          break;
        default:
          # code...
          break;
      }
    endif;
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  $salida = '<ul class="products">';
    $salida .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
      $salida .= '<div class="elementos_lista">';
        $salida .= '<ul>';
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $salida .= '<li>'; 
            $product_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail');
            $url = get_permalink();
            $salida .='<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">';
            $salida .= '<div class="row list_product_paradise">';
            if ($product_thumbnail_url):
              $salida .= '<div class="col-xs-2 image_product_thumbnail">';
              $salida .= '<img src="'. $product_thumbnail_url[0] .'" class="img-responsive" alt="'.get_the_title() .'">';
              $salida .= '</div>';
              $salida .= '<div class="product_cat col-xs-7">';
              $salida .= get_the_title();
              $salida .=  '</div>';
            else:
              $salida .= '<div class="product_cat col-xs-9">';
              $salida .= get_the_title();
              $salida .=  '</div>';
            endif;
            $salida .='<div class="total_items col-xs-3">';
            $salida .=  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
            $salida .=  '</div>';
            $salida .=  '</div>';
            $salida .=  '</a>';
            $salida .= '</li>'; 
          endwhile;
        endif;
        $salida .=  '</ul>';
      $salida .=  '</div>';
    $salida .=  '</div>';
  $salida .=  '</ul>';
  $salida .= '<div class="map_paradise"></div>';
  echo $salida;
  exit();

}

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter_product', 'filter_product' );    // If called from admin panel
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_product', 'filter_product' );    // If called from front end
```