# WordPress admin-ajax.php always return 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm wrote WordPress ajax plugin but admin-ajax.php always return 0 and don't work.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request','example_ajax_request' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'test', plugins_url( 'actions/js/test.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_localize_script( 'test', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

function example_ajax_request() {
    echo"d";
    die();
}
```

My javascrip test.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var fruit = 'Banana';
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

How this work?

Thanks.

Comment: `url: ajaxurl` should be `url: ajax_url`.

Comment: @FerdiKUCUK A comment is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your query script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url, // =================> HERE is the problem
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

You need to use **`ajax_object`** with **`ajax_url`** defined in **`wp_localize_script()`** this way:

```
url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
```

Reference:

- [Wordpress passing ajax value to a specific page using Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678914/wordpress-passing-ajax-value-to-a-specific-page-using-wordpress/37685212#37685212)